# library not found for -lSystem

Tags: ios

When I try compile version for device I has this error

ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I try remove all frameworks and libraries and this error still stay.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstall xCode and problem has been resolved